# jQuery infinite value change with delay

Tags: jquery, infinite-loop

Is it possible to change value in `div` from `list` items.

Example:

I've a list with items :

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

And I've empty `div` where I need to put values

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

How can I loop thru list items ( `li` ) and put value into `#output` with 5seconds delay. Once loop is finished, need to start from begin and go infinite. Also loop should't crash browser.

Also there can be many lists and output div's.

Comment: What have you tried? Getting and setting content is a very common task with thousands of samples on the internet

Comment: I didn't find right solutions, always had infinite loops and browser craches.

Comment: Show the script that crashes browser. I believe it can be fixed

Comment: function doTimeOut(x) {
        setTimeout(function() { $('.output').html(x) }, 600);  
    }
    
    $(function() {
        var items = $('.list li')
        for(var x = 0; x <= items.length; ++x) {
            if(x == items.length) {
                x = 0;
            } else {
                doTimeOut(x);
            }
        }
    });

Comment: put new code in the question itself where it is readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the OP script, posted in the question comment:

```
function doTimeOut(x) { 
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#output').html(x) 
    }, 600); 
} 
$(function() { 
    var items = $('.list li') for(var x = 0; x <= items.length; ++x) { 
        if(x == items.length) {
            // you start the loop over again here: 
            x = 0; 
        } else { 
            // you're updating the #output div x times in basically same time:
            doTimeOut(x); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

The above doesn't work, simply because when the `for` loop reaches highest `x`, then `x` is set down to **0** (`x = 0;`) and starts counting over again. Therefore browser is crashing.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/okwsbz23/) is fixed script using your scenario.
But for that purposes, there's no reason to use **setTimeout** and **for** loop together. Use **setinterval** instead.
Something like:

```
$(function () {

    function getVlaues() {
        $('#output').html($('#list li').length);
    }
    setInterval(getVlaues, 5000);

});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/54mf48b9/)**

Answer (score 0):

I've done this like this :

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        <ul class="list">
            <li>Item</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="output"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
$('.row .cell').each(function(){
    var wrapper = $(this);
    var maxValue = wrapper.find('.list li').length
    var currentValue = 1;

    var item = wrapper.find('.list li')[0]

    if(maxValue >= 2) {
        wrapper.find('.output').html(item.innerText).delay(5700).fadeOut(300);
        function getValues() {
            if(currentValue == maxValue) {
                currentValue = 0;
            }
            var item = wrapper.find('.list li')[currentValue]   
            wrapper.find('.output').html(item.innerText).fadeIn(300).delay(5400).fadeOut(300);
            currentValue++;
        }
        setInterval(getValues, 6000);
    } else {
        wrapper.find('.output').html(item.innerText);
    }
 });
```